# Django raising error in forms with the hidden field still remain issue

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an application where users can send each other messages.

The function I am working on is called read, allows the user to read the message he receives.

The way my model works in the following manner: Every message is related to a thread and this will used to keep track of replied messages related to each other.

My function works by capturing the message id and filtering all the messages related to the message thread.  Then I will populate a form with the current message id and allow the user to reply to the form.

When the user submits via POST, I will retrieve the hidden message id and create a new message using the retrieved message id thread.

The issue: I can't figure out how to raise an error for such situation when exceeding the character limit and populating the current message id with the raised error. Can someone kindly help me?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

Views:

```
@login_required
def read(request,id):

    try:
        messages = Message.objects.get(pk=id,recipient=request.user) 
    except Message.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Display'))
    messages.read = True
    messages.save()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = ReplyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            id = request.POST.get('hidden_field', False)
            try:
                messages = Message.objects.get(pk=id ,recipient=request.user,sentmessage=True,draft=False)

           except Message.DoesNotExist or Thread.DOesNotExist:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))
            person = Person.objects.get(user=messages.user)
            if person.inbox == "D":
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))
            body = form.cleaned_data['body']

            Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=messages.user,body=body,thread=messages.thread,sentmessage=True,read=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))

    message = Message.objects.filter(thread=messages.thread ).filter(created__lte=messages.created)
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)

    initial = {}
    initial.update({'hidden_field': messages.id})
    form = ReplyForm(initial=initial)

    return render(request,'read.html',{'messages':messages,'form':form,'message':message,'person':person})
```

forms

```
class ReplyForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=False,max_length=555)
    hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Template:

```
<div class="box22">




{% for m in message  %}

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="user">{{m.user.username}} </div>
<div class="message">{{m.body}}</div>
</div>

{% endfor %}


<form method="POST" >{% csrf_token %}
{{form.body}}{{form.hidden_field}}
<input type = "submit" value= "send" class="sen"/>
</form>


{{form.body.errors}}
```

Comment: Can I take a look at `ReplyForm`?

Comment: One small note: you are using `models.CharField(max_length=1000)`, it will be a bug when you run in production. If you want any amount more than 255, please use `TextField()`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend you use only `form.cleaned_data` to get submited data.

```
id = form.cleaned_data['hidden_field']
```

Also, why you reassign `id` from request.POST data when you already have `id` defined in your function args? Maybe it should look like:

```
msg_response_id = form.cleaned_data['hidden_field']
```

Then, you always need to check `hidden_field` value and you can do it with your custom clean method. Add `clean_hidden_field` method to your form and also you should override **init** form method and pass `id` and `msg_response_id`.

In your views:

```
form = ReplyForm(initial=initial, id=id, msg_response_id=msg_response_id)
```

And forms:

```
class ReplyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs.pop('id', None)
        self.msg_response_id = kwargs.pop('msg_response_id', None)
        super(ReplyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_hidden_field(self):
        if self.id and self.msg_response_id and self.id == self.msg_response_id:
            #  Raise form error, which will appear in your template.
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('You can't reply to your own message.'))
```

Comment: ok , i tried ur solution . it still wouldn't let me raise an error

Comment: ok wait , sorry I didn't reply earlier . my net keep disconnecting

Answer (score 1):

The last paragraph describing what you want is not all too clear, but I believe what you are trying to do, is make an raise an exception when a certain requirement is not met in your form.

If that is the case, then simply catching an `ValidationError` which is inbuilt into django will do the trick.

So, something like this:

```
try:
    form = ReplyForm(request.POST)
except ValidationError:
    # do what you want here
```

Alternatively,

```
form = ReplyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # do stuff
else:
    raise ValidationError
```

If this does not work for you, then you might try validation the post-data without using django-forms, but usually django takes care of this problem for you, and it will automatically generate the error messages. You can take a deeper look @ [form validation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/).

However if you want even more fine grain control you can make the form yourself, and handle the validation within your views. Otherwise, `ValidationError` should do the trick and let you redirect the error messages.

Comment: hmm , may i ask , how come you don't check if form is valid?

Comment: @JackRoster: Changed.